# Incomplete ResultSet data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

```
    Comment comment;
     ArrayList<Comment> commentList = null;

     try{
         ConnectionFactory myFactory = ConnectionFactory.getFactory();
         Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection();
         int i = 1; int j = 1; int k = 1;

         PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM COMMENT WHERE deletestatus = 0 and workid = ?");

         PreparedStatement pstmtLName = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM LEADER WHERE leaderid = ?");

         PreparedStatement pstmtMName = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE memberid = ?");

         pstmt.setInt(i++, Integer.parseInt(projid));

         ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
         System.out.print(rs);
         commentList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
         while(rs.next())
            {
                comment = new Comment();
                comment.setDetails(rs.getString("details"));
                comment.setDateadded(rs.getTimestamp("dateadded"));
                comment.setUrgency(rs.getInt("urgency"));



                if(rs.getInt("leaderid") != 0){
                    comment.setLeaderid(rs.getInt("leaderid"));

                    pstmtLName.setInt(j++, rs.getInt("leaderid"));

                    ResultSet rs2 = pstmtLName.executeQuery();


                    if(rs2.next()){
                    comment.setFullname(rs2.getString("firstname") +" " + rs2.getString("lastname"));
                    }
                }
                if(rs.getInt("memberid") != 0) {
                    comment.setMemberid(rs.getInt("memberid"));

                    System.out.print("in the loop");

                    pstmtMName.setInt(j++, rs.getInt("memberid"));
                    ResultSet rs3 = pstmtMName.executeQuery();

                    if(rs2.next()){
                    comment.setFullname(rs3.getString("firstname") +" " + rs3.getString("lastname"));
                    }

                }   

                comment.setProjid(Integer.parseInt(projid));
                commentList.add(comment);
            }



         return commentList;
     }
```

The problem with the code above is that it only gives back the first result of the result set.

When i removed both of the `IF` clauses in the `WHILE(RS.NEXT)` clause, it returned all the needed results but incomplete information because what i also need the query inside the if statement.

Please do help if you guys know the exact problem and tell me if you guys need more info. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, The problem seems at

```
pstmtLName.setInt(j++, rs.getInt("leaderid"));
pstmtMName.setInt(j++, rs.getInt("memberid"));
```

The value of j would be increased for each true condition till loop iteration.
Thus,it increases your `parameterIndex` of prepapred statement.

It should be

```
pstmtLName.setInt(1, rs.getInt("leaderid"));
pstmtMName.setInt(1, rs.getInt("memberid"));
```

Comment: the declaration was in the wrong place in this context. this solution worked perfectly! thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `int k` but did not use it. I assume you wanted to use it to set `memberid` parameter.
Change

```
pstmtMName.setInt( j++, rs.getInt( "memberid" ) );
```

to

```
pstmtMName.setInt( k++, rs.getInt( "memberid" ) );
```

and it should be working.

And I wonder why you use `i++`, `j++` and `k++` to set the param values of the statement when there is only one parameter marker `?` seen in the query. You should directly be using `pstObject.setInt( 1, ...`. Otherwise, if `rs` fetches more than a record where `leaderid != 0` and `memberid != 0`, they would cause an increment for the marker index, say `pstObject.setInt( 2, ...`, which is an invalid parameter in your query case and throws and `SQLException`.

As you are repeatedly using the same `pstObject` in a while loop, I would like to suggest using [`pstObject.clearParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#clearParameters%28%29) to clear current parameter values. Though this is optional, in some cases it is useful to immediately release the resources used by the current parameter values.

Comment: Apologies for the mis-declaration. I really dont need the k there. I expect the code to go only to one of the IF clauses however, i did not make it an if else just in case any anomaly in the database happens, there would be less markup for errors. 

though thanks for the pstObject advice! will do put it there! Thanks!